# What is the purpose of an exit Outlet in iOS?

Tags: ios

Say I have two view controllers vc1 and vc2. In vc2 a buttonClick2 is made.
When I control drag vc2's buttonClick2 outlet onto vc1(instead of vc2) I get an exit action outlet which I can custom name. What is the purpose of this outlet??, because I ain't able to execute any code in this. Can we use this to perform an update on vc1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Exit outlet** is for performing reverse-segue(**unwind segue**). An unwind segue (sometimes called exit segue) can be used to navigate back through push, modal or popover segues (as if you popped the navigation item from the navigation bar, closed the popover or dismissed the modally presented view controller).

If you are more interested in finding out what we can achieve with this, please go here. [UnwindSegue-turorial](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/)

Comment: ok but what is the purpose of the action function I get when I control drag from a button residing in vc2 to vc1 class..

Comment: Basically, it's giving you suggestion of unwind segue. So when you click on that button in vc2, you can navigate back to vc1.

Comment: ok seems like I tried to use it in the wrong way. thanks for clearing it.

Comment: Please accept the answer, in case it clarified your doubt. Because it might help to some other person having same doubt. :)